# Using custom JS event handler inside Gradio

Tags: javascript, python, iframe, gradio, gradio-chatinterface

I have a Gradio chatbot app exposed through the iframe. The main application component is the new [Gradio ChatInterface](https://www.gradio.app/docs/chatinterface). I want to pass some sensitive data from the parent app using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API (example [here](https://javascriptbit.com/transfer-data-between-parent-window-and-iframe-postmessage-api/)).

Gradio documentation specifies how to [add a custom js](https://www.gradio.app/guides/custom-CSS-and-JS#custom-js), triggered by a component event, but only some helper methods, and I need to:

1. Set up an event listener on load of the app or on a click of a button
2. Pass the data from the event listener into the python code so I can use it